# Show all items that Match in XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, match

This is my XML file named: full.xml
[image: a busy cat]

I need your help. I need a PHP script that open "**full.xml**"
and only display all values of the nodes that have **.email**

Example of the Output I want:

sales@company1.com

sales@company2.com

sales@company3.com

Thanks! I will thank you so much!

**EDIT**

```
$Connect = simplexml_load_file("full.xml");
return $Connect->table[0]->*.email;
```

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried and we'll help as much as we can. Here is a good place to start: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php

Comment: I tried:
$Connect = simplexml_load_file("full.xml");
return $Connect->table[0]->*.email;

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: It doesn't know anything.

Comment: But this: 
$Connect = simplexml_load_file("full.xml");
return $Connect->table[0]->company1.email;

This script: show: sales@company1.com

Comment: Then it looks like you're getting close!

Comment: Show your response using print_r($Connect);

Comment: I have this:
$Connect = simplexml_load_file("$dbfile.xml");
print_r($Connect);

Output is:


SimpleXMLElement Object ( [table] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [company1.email] => sales@company1.com [company2.email] => sales@company2.com [company3.email] => sales@company3.com [company1.tel] => 855xxxx [company2.tel] => 866xxxxxx [company3.tel] => 877xxxxx ) )

Comment: @Manuel Please POST your results by EDITing your question instead of using the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design of your XML is not very smart. With this `xpath` expression, you select all nodes with `.email` at the end of their name:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$results = $xml->xpath("//*[substring(name(),string-length(name())-" . (strlen('.email') - 1) . ") = '.email']");
```

--> result is an array with the selected nodes.

BTW: if you have any chance of CHANGING the structure of the XML, AVOID combining information within node names like `<company1.email>`, but do it like this:

```
...
<companies>
    <company id="1">
        <email>info@company1.com</email>
        <tel>+498988123456</tel>
        <name>somename</name>
    </company>
    <company id="2">
        <email>info@company2.com</email>
        <tel>+498988123457</tel>
        <name>someothername</name>
    </company>
</companies>
....
```

It will be much easier to read and parse.

Comment: Hey That's is a great Idea!
How can I make something like that?

Comment: @Manuel you can't if you get that XML from someplace else. If you're the author of the XML, you can. Pls consider to accept my answer by clicking on the tick on the left.